# wrong order in typo3 tt_content

Tags: sorting, typo3

in typo3 tt_content the field sorting doesn't show the real order of the elements of a page. Is there any possibility to reorder it, to refresh it?

I want in a selection the bodytext and image of the first Contentelement (textpic) of a page.

Thanks
Volker

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get your question but the order is correct in the backend, however you need to have some things in mind

- the sorting depends on the page (field pid), so you can't compare sorting over multiple plages
- The field **colPos** is also important as sorting is unique per column

Comment: Additionally there might be extensions like flux/fluidcontent, gridelements or multicolumn involved, that provide nested content with an own sorting within their sub-columns.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. In my installation in the tt_content is not updating the field "sorting" after a clean installation the problem is solved.

Thanks 
Volker

Answer (score 0):

A try of a concrete answer to a vague question:

```
lib.someContent = CONTENT
lib.someContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    where = colPos=0
    orderBy = sorting
    languageField = sys_language_uid
    begin = 0
    max = 1
  }
}
```